# shiny: Aligning inputPanel and wellPanel, or using another widget

Tags: css, r, shiny

**I am trying to set up a shiny app where a user inputs a value, and there are 2 boxes that have set values in the same row as the input box.**  The set values in these other 2 boxes will be numeric, but they just need to be displayed in those boxes.

I used `wellPanel` to display the 2 boxes that contain set values.

**The issue I am trying to fix is having all 3 of these boxes line up nicely together**.  As a result, I am wondering if there was another shiny widget other than wellPanel to do what I am trying to do, or if there is a way to align them (wellPanel did not seem to have much in the way of arguments, and I'm not sure how else to align them).  In the real app there are a bunch of other input boxes that are nicely aligned below these top 3 boxes.

Below is the example image, where you can see the `numericInput` box is not aligned with the `wellPanel` boxes that are meant to hold ranges.

[image]

**Here is the simple reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(headerPanel("Test app"),
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 3,
                    numericInput(
                      inputId = "x",
                      label = "Input number",
                      value = "",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 500
                    )
                  ),
                  column(width = 3,
                         wellPanel("low range value")),
                  column(width = 3,
                         wellPanel("high range value"))
                ))

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {}

# Run
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other option is that you work with ShinyDashboard, and there you have more possibilities, one of them is the valueBox component. Here the code example:
[valueBox in Shiny dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ApY.png)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(fluidRow(
                      column(
                        width = 3,
                        numericInput(
                          inputId = "x",
                          label = "Input number",
                          value = "",
                          min = 0,
                          max = 500
                        )
                      ),
                      column(
                        width = 3,
                        valueBox(width = 12, format(54500, big.mark = ","),
                          "low range value", icon = icon("coins"), color = "blue")
                      ),
                      column(
                        width =  3,
                        valueBox(width = 12, format(18754500, big.mark = ","),
                                 "long range value", icon = icon("fire"), color = "orange")
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )

server <- function(input, output) {}

# Run
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This was as close as I could figure out to make work, so I will accept, thanks.